# select user with checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, material-ui

I want to create `checkbox` for every user in the table, this my `tableBody` :

```
<TableBody>
  {users.map((user) => {
    return (
      <TableRow key={user.id}>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            checked={selectedUserIds.indexOf(user.id) !== -1} // check if the user.id is in selectedUserIds
            onChange={() => handleSelectUser(user.id)} // evrytime I try to find the logic for this function I fail
            value="true"
          />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>{user.email}</TableCell>
        <TableCell>{user.roles}</TableCell>
        <TableCell>{user.status}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  })}
</TableBody>;
```

I have created this `hook` for storing the selected ids as shown in the example above

```
const [selectedUserIds, setSelectedUserIds] = useState([]);
```

The problem is that I can't logic for the function `handleSelectUser` that add/remove the user checked/unchecked in/from `selectedUserIds` I tried so many times and I failed.

If someone can help me I will be very thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleSelectUser = (id) => {
  const selectedIndex = selectedUserIds.indexOf(id); // try to find the id in the array
  let newSelectedUserIds = [];

  if (selectedIndex === -1) { // if it does not exist
    newSelectedUserIds = newSelectedUserIds.concat(selectedUserIds, id);
   } else if (selectedIndex === 0) { // if it is the first element
      newSelectedUserIds = newSelectedUserIds.concat(selectedUserIds.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selectedUserIds.length - 1) { // if it is the last element
      newSelectedUserIds = newSelectedUserIds.concat(selectedUserIds.slice(0, -1));
   } else if (selectedIndex > 0) { // found but in the midldle
    newSelectedUserIds = newSelectedUserIds.concat(
      selectedUserIds.slice(0, selectedIndex),
      selectedUserIds.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
    );
  }

  setSelectedUserIds(newSelectedUserIds);
};
```

learn more about [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```js
const handleSelectUser = (userId) => {
  // Check if the userId is already in selectedUserIds
  if (selectedUserIds.includes(userId)) {
    // If yes, remove it from selectedUserIds
    setSelectedUserIds(selectedUserIds.filter((id) => id !== userId));
  } else {
    // If no, add it to selectedUserIds
    setSelectedUserIds([...selectedUserIds, userId]);
  }
};
```